# Positioning outside Iframes

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to the position of the embedded iframe to relatively position certain elements in the parent DOM. I tried this out.

```
var iframe_posy = $('iframe').css('top');
var iframe_posx = $('iframe').css('left');

<iframe src="game/game.html" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 600px;">...</iframe>
```

When I log iframe_posx and iframe_posy, I get 'undefined'. Anything that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery, use [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) , that is, `$('iframe').position().left` and `$('iframe').position().top`

Answer (score 0):

They won't be defined unless you define them in the CSS, or they are defined by the browser's bootstrap CSS, or, like @Ingenu suggested, you use JavaScript to grab the position.

Add the top and left to the css and your code works:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" style="border: 0; position:relative; left:300px; top:200px; width: 100%; height: 600px;"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/r6hhf/